# @PreAuthorize when method invocation is not allowed , got 405 not Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Problem:**
`@PreAuthorize`  when method invocation is not allowed  , got 405 not Request method 'POST' not supported.

**Case:**
if the `@PreAuthorize` result is true, all works OK, but if it returns false (not allowed) , i got a error : 405 not Request method 'POST' not supported. i expect to receive access denied page.

Security Config:

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
 
 @Autowired 
 @Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
 AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  
  auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
 }


 @Override
 public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web
       .ignoring()
          .antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
 }
 

 
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll() 
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()                                    
                .permitAll()
                .and() 
             .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied");
    }
 
 
 @Bean 
 @Override
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
      return super.authenticationManagerBean();
 }
 
}
```

WebMvcConfig :

```html
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true,prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{ 

// My config

}
```

My Controller :_

```html
  

@Secured("ROLE_SAVE")
  @PreAuthorize("((#myModel.cod== 'A') and  hasRole('ROLE_AUTH'))")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyModel myModel,
             BindingResult br,  RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
      
          ... my code ...
             
     }
```

Note: i already include a   CSRF token in request.

Why i receive error 405 post not supported?